# QQmlComponent from module item

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I want to create instance of `QQmlComponent` from `QML` script text instead of from a file, something like:

```
QQmlComponent comp(engine, "import QtQml 2.0; Item {}");
```

which would be the exact analogue of:

```
import QtQml 2.0

Component {
    Item {}
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use [void QQmlComponent::setData(const QByteArray &data, const QUrl &url)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcomponent.html#setData):

```
QQmlComponent component(&engine);
component.setData("import QtQuick 2.7\n; Item {}", QUrl());
component.create();
```